# Is it ok to have many fxml include to the same fxml

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, fxml

```
  <fx:include source="MyCombo.fxml" fx:id="combo1" maxWidth="Infinity" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"  />
  <Label text="Depotstelle" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
  <fx:include source="MyCombo.fxml" fx:id="combo2" maxWidth="Infinity" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2"  />
  <TextField fx:id="referenceText" maxWidth="Infinity" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
  <fx:include source="MyCombo.fxml" fx:id="combo3" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
```

In the fxml above I have many fxml include tags that uses the same source fx:include source="**MyCombo.fxml**". Is ok to do that? Will affect the performance of the FXML loader doing that (I'm thinking at I/O operations)?

Answer (score 2):

It should be fine.  You don't say how many "many" is.  More than a thousand includes would probably be too many, but less than fifty includes, of small fxml files like your combo box definition likely is, shouldn't cause an issue.

If you are having any problems with the performance of your current design, you should run some benchmarks to see where the slow points are.  If you aren't having any performance issues, then I wouldn't worry about it and would advise you just to choose the clearest design and implementation that works for you.

As an aside and as a way to tackle and consider such questions as you have posed here, you may be interested in reading some generic background information on analyzing [which design is faster](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) (which is not specific to your question).

Comment: I want to know if the FXML loader does many i/o operations or it caches the content for the next reading of MyCombo.fxml

Comment: Then benchmark the loading process for our FXML files or study the loader source code to find out.